# The access scope of Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I tried to run a docker container application which accesses Cloud Datastore in the Cloud Shell, but the access was refused. I suspect that the Cloud Shell doesn't have the scope to access Cloud Datastore.

Is it possible to add an appropriate scope the Cloud Shell instance?

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Comment: Here's the last part of errer.

-----

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/contrib/gce.py", line 134, in _refresh self._retrieve_info(http_request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/contrib/gce.py", line 117, in _retrieve_info

    self.service_account_email = info['email']

TypeError: string indices must be integers

-----

Sorry, the problem was not the scope, but the auth account. Service account is not used by default in Cloud Shell, and this caused the error. How can I force the container app to use the service account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in Cloud Shell credential handling where using newer versions of Python oauth2client package (either directly or indirectly) would fail with error like

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/contrib/gce.py", line 117, in _retrieve_info 
self.service_account_email = info['email']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This should be fixed in the newer image release.  New sessions of Cloud Shell should not have this issue.  Here is a working example of using Cloud Datastore API in a container, running in Cloud Shell:

`$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM python
RUN pip install gcloud
COPY test.py .
CMD ["python", "test.py"]`

`$ cat test.py 
from gcloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client(project='your-project-id-23242')
query = datastore.Query(client, kind='EntityKind')
print(list(query.fetch()))`

`$ docker build -t test .
... docker output ...`

`$ docker run -ti test
[]`

The example prints out just an empty list because I don't have any entities of "EntityKind" kind in my project's datastore, but you get the idea.

P.S. I work at Google.

Comment: This seems to be back